# WooCommerce Cart Link based on Cookie Values

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to create a URL to include in emails that a customer can click to open their previously created cart in WooCommerce.

It appears that Woo creates three cookies for a cart.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-cookies/

Here are the values for a sample cart:

---

Name: wp_woocommerce_session_c8a4c49d4ac503b1c8f1fb01af7b58dd

Value: 0c4832f2e3dee4b465082d8da8ec0eb8%7C%7C1477671079%7C%7C1477667479%7C%7Cc0a028f480838529ead6a6bceb9445da

---

Name: woocommerce_items_in_cart

Value: 1

---

Name: woocommerce_cart_hash

Value: 6c3d2226001920d656654a0252bdbac4

---

Woo's standard cart page UR is: https://basketballgoalstore.com/cart/

I've tried appending the values using querystrings to this URL but it doesn't work.  Is there any way to retrieve a customers cart from a URL, a URL that will work in any browser?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm interested in understanding the same. Thanks.

Comment: No, I never found a solution...sorry.